# My view is not binding the angular module

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Hi this is my first day in angular and trying to play around with some code however I am lost around with the app.js file which throws error as `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

Here is my structure of application which I cloned from angular-seed and did some cleanup.

`index.html`

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Currency Converter</title>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="app.js"></script> 
    <script src="finance.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyAppCtrl as app">
        <b>Currency Converter</b>
        <div>
            <input type="number" ng-model="app.amount" required >
            <select ng-model="app.inCurr">
                <option ng-repeat="c in app.currencies">{{c}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="number" ng-model="app.amount" required >
            <select ng-model="app.inCurr">
                <option ng-repeat="c in app.currencies">{{c}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

`app.js`

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp', ['finance']);
    .controller('MyAppCtrl', ['currencyConverter', function(currencyConverter) {
        this.amount=1;
        this.inCurr="EUR";
        this.currencies=currencyConverter.currencies;
    }]);
}());
```

`finance.js`

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('finance', []);
    .factory('currencyConverter', ['$http', function($http) {
        //var yahoo_finance_rest_api=https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?   q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22EURUSD%22%2C%22GBPUSD%22%2C%22EURGBP%22%2C%22CNYUSD%22%2C%22CNYGBP%22%2C%22CNYEUR%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=
        var currencies = ['USD', 'EUR', 'CNY', 'GBP'];
    }]);
}());
```

Any idea what's going wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`angular.module('myApp', ['finance']);`, the `;` terminates the statement. remove it and it'll work.

Comment: no it doesn't I tried it and it throws next error `Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined `

Comment: well, you do need to include a `<script>` that points to a file with angular in it...